# Found this insect in my bedroom. What is it?

Tags: species-identification

I found this bug in my bedroom yesterday. I was afraid that it was a tick so I got rid of it after taking some photos.
The bug was found in Denmark and was about half a nail in size. 
 Can somebody recognize it?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Photos with a less cluttered background may help; from what I can see though, I'm thinking a beetle belonging to the superfamily Scarabaeoidea (dung beetles and chafers -- I think we can eliminate stag beetles) but would like a closer view of the front of the animal (that we can't zoom in for any of the photos is a handicap).  Once we get those photos someone else will have a better chance of going deeper (it won't be me; I don't know the Danish fauna of the group I think we see here).

Comment: Thank you, @ArthurJFrost. I think that the background gives a perspective on the size of the beetle because it is not much bigger than the paint spatter. Do you still think the the pictures should be cropped?
I can't take more pictures of the beetle so if you don't think that anyone can determine the fauna from these photos, then leave your comment as an answer.